# Read file line by line and create lists

Tags: python

I have a file which contains lines of the form

```
2.484 5.234
6.123 1.461
1.400 9.381
```

I would like to read these into python lists **x** containing the first value of each line and **y** containing the second value of each line.

How can I achieve this? Here is my attempt:

```
x = []
y = []
with open(filename) as file_:
    for line in file_:
        a, b = line
        x.append(a)
        y.append(b)
```

Comment: `a, b = map(float,line.split())` and you're done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a, b = line
```

cannot work because you're trying to unpack a string into 2 elements (unless the string itself is 2 elements long, which isn't the case)

you want to convert to float & unpack the splitted line like this:

```
a, b = map(float,line.split())
```

in that case `split()` without arguments takes care of multiple spaces, linefeeds, tabs... like `awk` would do so it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
data =[map(float, i.strip('\n').split()) for i in open('filename.txt')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that

```
x = []
y = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as ins:
    for line in ins:
        elt = line.split()
        x.append(elt[0])
        y.append(elt[1])

print x
print y
```